# Ошибка формата при сохранении модели в Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Всем привет,

При сохранении/update модели ( в Laravel 5.5 ) с полем

```
`updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
```

получаю ошибку

```
(1/1) InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data
in Carbon.php (line 582)
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-09-09 11:22:00')
in HasAttributes.php (line 715)
at Model->asDateTime('2017-09-09 11:22:00')
in HasAttributes.php (line 738)
at Model->fromDateTime('2017-09-09 11:22:00')
in HasAttributes.php (line 1062)
at Model->originalIsEquivalent('updated_at', '2017-09-09')
in HasAttributes.php (line 1023)
at Model->getDirty()
in Model.php (line 613)
at Model->performUpdate(object(Builder))
in Model.php (line 531)
at Model->save()
in Client.php (line 408)
```

Текущее значение поля updated_at в базе '2017-09-09 11:22:00' и вызывает интерес строка

```
at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-09-09 11:22:00')
```

Похоже, проблема в первом параметре формата даты?
Этот параметр где-то нужно установить в настройках ?

Спасибо !

Comment: можно в модельке свойство `dateFormat` прописать. `protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";`

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в виду твк :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Validator;
use DB;
use App\MyRestfulModel;
use App\Department;
use App\Order;
use App\ClientImage;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use App\library\ListingReturnData;

class Client extends MyRestfulModel
{
    protected $table = 'client';
    protected $primaryKey = 'client_id';
    protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
    ...
```

Не помогает и ошибка остается...

```
Если добавить свойство
```

public $timestamps = false;

```
то поле updated_at не апдейтиться вовсе и, наверно, я могу добавить текущее время в updated_at поле при сохранении... 
Но есть лучше решение?

Эта  база не моя - и хотелось бы решения на стороне laravel без модификации таблицы...
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополните формат даты, внеся туда время.

**Было:**

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-09-09 11:22:00')
```

**Стало:**

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-09 11:22:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка действительно может возникать из-за того, что НЕ соответствует формат времени и переданное время в виде строки.
То есть ошибка возникает на уровне Carbon - этот класс не может создать экземпляр из строки, поскольку строка, содержащая время, не соответствует указанному формату.

## Решение

Необходимо использовать

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-09-09 11:22:00')
```